# Connection to secondary DB in AlwaysOn High Availability

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, connections

I need some clarification regarding Always on avilabilty group in SQL SERVE 2016 connection to the secondary DB. Now i have availability group with 2 nodes.

[image]

For the main application connection string I am expecting it to be  this

```
SQLSERVER=Listener;databseName=unicas_ux;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

If I want another report application to connect to the secondary DB. The connection string should be point to secondary  or the listener

Also, i when i try to connect to the  databases secondary server with a SQL authentication user i failed.

[image]

**This has been solved by make the SID in secondary match the primary SID**

Comment: You should really push everything app wise through the listener. As for the database availability on the secondary, have you checked that the SID for the login matches the SID on the primary?

Comment: Nic , how can i force the connection to  read from the secondary

Comment: The SID don't match. how can i update it in the secondary

Comment: I was able to change the SID and can connect the the secondary. thanks.

Comment: What version of management studio are you using? also can you check the sql server error log and see if you get some clue in there?

Comment: @sebeid You should make your comment into the answer since it fixed the OP's issue.